# Ember.js: there is no route named 'new-table'

Tags: ember.js

Here are my routes definition:

```
Router.map(function() {
    this.resource('servers', { path: '/' }, function() {
      this.resource('server', { path: '/servers/:serverid'}, function () {
          this.resource('databases', { path: '/databases' }, function () {
              this.resource('database', { path: '/:databaseid'}, function () {
                  this.resource('catalogues', { path: '/catalogues' });
                  this.resource('eventtriggers', { path: '/eventtriggers' });
                  this.resource('extensions', { path: '/extensions' });
                  this.resource('schemas', { path: '/schemas' }, function () {
                      this.resource('schema', { path: '/:schemaid' }, function () {
                          this.resource('tables', { path: '/tables' }, function () {
                              this.route('new-table', function () {});

                              this.resource('table', { path: '/:tableid' });
                          });
                      });
                  });
                  this.resource('replication', { path: '/replication' });
              });
          });
      });
    });
});
```

And the code used to generate link to `new-table` route goes as follows:

`{{#link-to 'new-table' schema.database.server.id schema.database.id schema.id}}`

And this gives me the error mentioned in this question's topic. However when I replace `this.route` call to `this.resource` everything works fine. So what am I doing wrong here? I'm using ember 1.13.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A resource defines the main entry point of a link-to. So if you create a resource `new-table` you can access it via `new-table` in the `link-to` helper. Routes on the other hand are children of a resource or another route, they should be prefixed with their parent route or resource. So in the example you gave, you can link to the `new-table` route by using `tables.new-table`.